# How can i send a notification from php server to the amazon kindle android device ?

Tags: php, android, push-notification, kindle-fire

How can i send a notification from php server to the amazon kindle android device ? As from tutorial i come to know that, the kindle device doesn't support the google APIs.

Comment: See Push notifications / C2DM for Kindle Fire?


   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439999/push-notifications-c2dm-for-kindle-fire

Answer (score 1):

[Amazon Device Messaging](https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/adm.html) is now available for the Kindle Fire series, forming an approximate equivalent to GCM available on more conventional Android devices.